# Need to kill one task if other is started

Tags: java, android

I have a code which is running asynchronously and it is called from the main thread. It can be called by main thread multiple number of times. I want to finish the earlier execution of the asynchronous task to be destroyed as soon as I start a new instance of it through main thread.

I tried it using cancel of AsyncTask in java. But calcel works only after doInBackground(params..). So this doesn't work

Can it be achieved in some way? I also tried putting this asyncronous task in thread. But don't know how to cancel the operation started by thread.

Comment: What u have done so far?, post the code

Answer (score 0):

In your thread declare a boolean *running*.  Then wrap the execution of doInBackground & onPostExecute in a *while running* statement.  Keep a reference to the asynctask, if not null, set running to false, which should kill the old task.  Then create a new one.

*Edit: by kill the old task, I mean cause it to complete early

Answer (score 0):

So here goes:

- you need to declare one class member of that type of task : `private MyTask mMyTask`
- in your `doInBackground()` method you will have to check from time to time if the task was canceled. If you have a `for loop` you will mostly do it in this way `for(int i=0;i<0;!isCancelled();i++)` or in a while loop `while(myCondition && !isCancelled()){...}`
- when you want to cancel your task do the following :`mMyTask.cancel(); mMyTask=new MyTask(); mMyTask.execute();`

Comment: I was doing the check in doInBackground() for isCancelled(). I am running a thread in doInBackground() for checking that. But don't know how to return from doInBackground() from after I detect cancellation.